# Second event handler cannot reach the global variable in the first event handler in jQuery?

Tags: events, scope, global

As you see in the following code snippet, selectedImageName variable is defined as global variable in first event handler. This global variable can be reached by the function afterRemoving() at the bottom of the code snippet, but this global variable cannot be reached by the second event handler and because of this, it outputs an error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedImageName is not defined* Could you explain what is going on? How can I handle this problem?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // There are some codes... 

    $(document).ajaxSuccess( function() {

        $("#imgOutput .removeInlineImage").on("click", function(){  

            selectedImageName = $(this).prev().val();
--------------------^ (Everything is OK.)

            optionsRemove = {
                url: 'bilesenler/ajaxRemoveImage.php?imgName=' + selectedImageName,
                beforeSubmit: beforeRemoving,  // pre-submit callback 
                success: afterRemoving,  // post-submit callback 
                resetForm: false        // reset the form after successful submit 
            };

            imgDelete = true;
            $("#addText").submit();
        });


        $("#imgOutput #imgName").on("keypress", function(){

            optionsUpdate = {
                url: 'jx.php?oldImgName=' + selectedImageName + '&newImgName=' + $(this).val(),
----------------------------------------------------^ (Trouble: Uncaught ReferenceError: selectedImageName is not defined)

                beforeSubmit: beforeUpdating,  // pre-submit callback 
                success: afterUpdating,  // post-submit callback 
                resetForm: false        // reset the form after successful submit 
            };

            imgUpdate = true;
            $("#addText").submit();
        });
    });
});

// There are some codes...

function afterRemoving(responseText){
    var temp = selectedImageName.split(".");
-----------------------^ (Everything is OK)

    selectedImageNameWithoutExtension = temp[0];

    $('#imgOutput #' + selectedImageNameWithoutExtension).hide();

    imgDelete = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless click event is triggered, selectedImageName is null. After clicking process, selectImageName is initialized.